# How to use 2 different database adapters (SQL Server and PostgreSQL) in Rails in the same environment?

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I'm working on a Rails 3 project which uses a PostgreSQL database.

I need to make queries on a remote SQL Server database sometimes (pure sql and stored procedures)

To do the trick I can use `TinyTDS` to access the SQL Server and execute queries:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: dblib
  host: 123.123.123.123
  port: 1433
  database: the_db_name
  username: the_user
  password: the_pwd
  timeout: 5000
```

It's working well, but I don't know how to use the 2 different database adapters at the same time.

Is it possible? Or maybe there's an other way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

In your database.yml file add another "environment" block for your postgres connection

example environment name might be

`postgres_development`

Then in your environment.rb file add the following Line

`[ModelName].establish_connection "postgres_#{RAILS_ENV}"`

Where [ModelName] is the ActiveModel object you wish to specifically connect to the other database environment. I am not sure if this works in rails 3 100% but I know it works in rails 2

Comment: You should be able to do the `establish_connection` call right inside the model: `class M < ActiveRecord::Base; establish_connection '...'; ...`.