# Rails application with two databases and two adapters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgis, postgresql-9.3

While a database.yml file can be configured to connect remotely to two databases, can the databases have distinct adapters?

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: main
  username: main_user

connect_remote:
  adapter: postgis
  database: secondary
  username: main_user
  schema_search_path: public, postgis
```

Is this possible and are there any drawbacks, gotchas (aside from app logic) ?

Comment: Possibly relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948913/how-to-use-2-different-database-adapters-sql-server-and-postgresql-in-rails-in This question is about using one db for some models and another db for different models, i don't know if that's quite your situation.

Comment: Absolutely you can do that. For example, you could have a mysql environment, a postgres environment and a SQL Lite environment if you wanted. 

The environments are completely seperate. 

As for gotchas, I think you may run into issues in your migrations if you stray from standards. For example, if you execute raw SQL code you will need to make sure it will succeed on all of the potential database flavors.

I can absolutely see a use for this, but I imagine it to be a relatively unique scenario. I would try to avoid this in most cases because I think it would be easy to have tricky issues.

Comment: @max, yes this is the case.  As the question alluded to there are some postgis calculations that need running.  However the main application needs to be in a master/slave set-up and a proper postgis adapter is not available.  So the goal is to have sub-master/master/slave set-up

Comment: Well, the way that other questions' answer works is that it tells the environment that specific models use a different database.  So, if you are careful to isolate* all of your postgis functionality within one or more model classes, and make sure that those classes don't need to make any calls to your "regular" database, then it looks like the way to go.  *(these classes can have methods which are called by non-postgis classes, that's fine).  You might want to put the postgis stuff in a module and have the relevant classes include it.